# Substract and compare SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi guys I have this query

```
UPDATE `account`.`account` SET `status` = 'Admin' 
WHERE `status` = 'User' AND `last_online`
```

What I'd like to do is to check the last time online and be sure that 10 minutes had passed since  last time online . Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Last_online is a timestamp in your database?  And when you say 'be sure that 10 minutes had passed' you mean until the time the query is run, or until some other time in the database?

Comment: Last_online is something like this 2013-03-23 07:20:35 , and what I want to do is to run the querry if the current date is 10 minutes more that the last_online

Comment: @user1638487 Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider accepting the answer that helped you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this::

```
UPDATE `account`.`account` SET `status` = 'Admin' 
WHERE `status` = 'User' AND TIMEDIFF(now(),`last_online`)>600
```

Answer (score 0):

Query the database for the most recent activity and then compare the dates before choosing to insert.